# Render an array of Objects that contain an object

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to loop through an array of objects. Each object contains an object one for each day. Im trying to look though the array catch the Object.key(forEach array Index) and under the key I log every value within it.

```
  DOPeration:[

        {
          'Monday':{
            Closed:'Closed Today'
          }
        },
        { Tuesday:{
            Closed:'Closed Today'
          }
        },
        { Wednesday:{
            Closed:'Closed Today'
          }
        },
        { Thursday:{
            Closed:'Closed Today'
          }
        },
        { Friday:{
            Closed:'Closed Today'
          }
        },
        { Saturday:{
            Closed:'Closed Today'
          }
        },
        { Sunday:{
            Closed:'Closed Today'
          }
        }
        ]
export default class displayDay extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const thing = this.props.dates.map(function(sec,index) {
      var keyVal = sec[Object.keys(sec)]


        return(
        <div key = {index}>
          <h9>{Object.keys(sec)[0]}</h9>
        <div>
        {

          for (var variable in keyVal) {
            return(
              <p>{variable}:{keyVal[variable]}</p>
            )
          }

        }</div>
        </div>
        )


    })
  return(
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='box'>
        {thing}
      </div>

    </div>
      )
  }
}
```

this kind of worked but only logged one value within each day so the forin loop only catches one value

```
// const thing = this.props.dates.map(function(sec,index) {
//   var keyVal = sec[Object.keys(sec)]
//   for (var variable in (keyVal)) {
//     console.log('keyVal',keyVal);
//
//     return(
//     <div key = {index}>
//       <h9>{Object.keys(sec)[0]}</h9>
//     <p>{variable}:{keyVal[variable]}</p>
//     </div>
//     )
//   }
//
// })
```

Comment: // const thing = this.props.dates.map(function(sec,index) {
//   var keyVal = sec[Object.keys(sec)]
//   for (var variable in (keyVal)) {
//     console.log('keyVal',keyVal);
//
//     return(
//     <div key = {index}>
//       <h9>{Object.keys(sec)[0]}</h9>
//     <p>{variable}:{keyVal[variable]}</p>
//     </div>
//     )
//   }
//
// })

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pull the actual key when you defined keyVal:

```
var keyVal = sec[Object.keys(sec)[0]]
```

Without the `[0]` you're trying to use an array as an object key.

---

Edit

That data is not great for rendering UI. You're going to be better off writing a function to convert that data into something more useful so you can keep your render method much cleaner. [Check this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/miroleboki/edit?js,console) for a formatting function. If you're using es6 that function can get more succinct.

Comment: Thats right, but it doesnt fix my problem. Still only logging one. I get unexpected token for my forin loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Edited answer to provide a different solution. Try converting your data to a more useful format before using it in your render function.

Answer (score 0):

strange code :D you only trying to get a section for each object in your data, right?
Try this

```js
<div>
    {this.props.dates.map((item, idx) => {
        const day = Object.keys(item)[0];
        return <div key={idx}>
            <h4>{day}</h4>
            <p>{item[day].Closed}</p>
        </div>
    })}
</div>
```